# Unable to find the enum reference which is declared in same namespace in .net 3.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have created a class library project which has number of classes and enums. All are declared in same name space. However, while compiling the class library itself some other classes/methods reports error that not fininding the reference to perticular enums. I have declared enum as public.

```
namespace CommonInterfaces
{
        public enum SettingsType
        {
              EnumType1,
        EnumTYpe2,
        EnumType3
        }
}

namespace CommonInterfaces
{
        public interface IPlayer
        {       
          void Add(SettingsType type); <-- Error occured.
       }
}
```

I tried giving full qualified name like CommonInterfaces.SettingsType but still it did not resove the problem. The exact error is

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'SettingsType' does not exist in the namespace 'CommonInterfaces'(are you missing an assembly reference?)

How to resolve the error?

Comment: Tried recompile the entire project? Somtimes that helps. Otherwise I would say that you need to provide code samples for this to be possible to answer.

Comment: No sub name spaces used? You should post the enum declaration as well a class that didn't find the declaration.

Comment: The class library consists of only one assembly?

Comment: Yes, both the enum and interface are part of same assembly. However they are declared in different source files of same project.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its nested in other class? Then u have to use it like this: `OtherClass.EnumName`. Its only idea i have now. Such error could be solved only by knowing ur source code or at least where u define Enum and where it cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this problem while using xamarin in vs2019. i  cleaned and rebuilt solution again and again but didnt work then i restarted visual studio and problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem in VS2019. Restarting Visual Studio solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks - others are DV this also solved my issue, even after trying clean and rebuild.